# Parameter datetime in asp.net mvc razor erroe with Gregorian

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I passing parameters datetime to the controller.

When I pass a hijri date, there's no problem, but when I pass a Gregorian date, the following error appears:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'DateOfBirth' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Get_Date_Birth(System.DateTime)' in 'EAMser.Controllers.ExamsAndAdmissionController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

I used this code in the controller:

```
public ActionResult Get_Date_Birth(DateTime DateOfBirth)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ViewBag.Get_B_date = My_code.Get_B_Date(DateOfBirth);

        return View("Index");
    }
    else 
        return View("Index");
}
```

And this markup in the view :

```
<body>
    <input type="text" width="120" height="30" id="DateOfBirth1" />
    <input type="submit" readonly="readonly" value=" هجري" id="Hdate" />
    <input type="submit" value=" ميلادي " id="Gdate" />
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Get_Date_Birth", "ExamsAndAdmission", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        //  @Html.Hidden("O_RecId")
        @Html.TextBox("DateOfBirth", "", new { @class = "form-control datepicker" })
               <input type="submit" readonly="readonly" value=" احسب العمر" />
        <hr />
        <p>عمر الطالب : </p>
        @ViewBag.Get_B_date
    }


</body>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Hijri/jquery.calendars.js"></script>
<script src="~/Hijri/jquery.calendars.plus.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Hijri/jquery.plugin.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Hijri/jquery.calendars.picker.js"></script>
<script src="~/Hijri/jquery.calendars.picker-ar.js"></script>
<script src="~/Hijri/jquery.calendars.islamic.js"></script>
<script src="~/Hijri/jquery.calendars.ummalqura.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/kbwood/calendars/2.1.0/dist/css/jquery.calendars.picker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#Hdate').calendarsPicker({
            calendar: $.calendars.instance('ummalqura'),
            showOtherMonths: false,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                $('#DateOfBirth').val(date[0].formatDate());
                $('#Hdate').val("  هجري  ");
         //       $("#O_RecId").val(date[0].formatDate());
            }
        });
        $('#Gdate').calendarsPicker({
            calendar: $.calendars.instance('gregorian'),
            showOtherMonths: false,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            onSelect: function (date) {
                $('#DateOfBirth').val(date[0].formatDate('yyyy/mm/dd'));
                $('#Gdate').val("  ميلادي  ");
        //        $("#O_RecId").val(date[0].formatDate());
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

How I can I solve this problem?

Thank very much...

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is using

```
<globalization culture="ar-SA" uiCulture="ar-SA" />
```

The variable datetime gives a null value with the Gregorian date and a valid value with the Hijri date

While when using

```
<globalization uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

It gives correct Hijri and Gregorian dates

How can I solve the problem ?
when using

```
<globalization culture="ar-SA" uiCulture="ar-SA" />
```

The variable datetime gives a valid value, whether it is the Hijri or Gregorian date

Thank you...